# Ajax gets executed before variable gets populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a chatjs bar graph where I have defined a click event that has an ajax call within it. On click I am also trying to get the value of a dropwdown menu and radio button both of which are bootstrap elements.

```
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function(evt) {

    var activeElement = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    var clickedElementIndex = activeElement[0]._index;
    var stype = myChart.data.labels[clickedElementIndex];

    $('.dropdown-menu a').find(function() {
        var mname = ($('#selected').text());
    });

    var listoption = ($('input[name=radioname]:checked', '#radioform').val());


    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'updatesession' %}",
        data: {
            stype: stype,
            listoption: listoption,
            mname: mname
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location = "{% url 'results' %}";
        }
    });

}
```

But the problem I am having is that the ajax call is executed before the mname variable is populated. The listoption variable however does get populated. How do I populate the variable before my ajax call. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are there a reason why have the function around the `var mname=($('#selected').text());` as it is a ID i assume the element is unique and can be selected without the function around it.

Comment: issue has to do with the fact that the variable `mname` is defined inside a block scope that is not available to the Ajax code. The way you declared it is wrong.

Comment: And I do not think you want find() like that....

Comment: @epascarello Yes that was an oversight. I will make sure to make the declaration outside my block. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try putting your ajax in the function for the dropdown menu like this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').find(function(){
    var mname=($('#selected').text());

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "{% url 'updatesession' %}",
        data:{
              stype : stype,
              listoption : listoption,
              mname : mname
        },
        success: function( data )
        { 
            window.location = "{% url 'results' %}";
        }
    });
});

var listoption=($('input[name=radioname]:checked', '#radioform').val());
```